# SharePoint 2013 - Warning Prompt before sharing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, javascript, script

I'd like to warn users before sharing a file or a site to "Everyone" by showing a pop up. Is there a way to do this ?

Maybe by editing the master-page on SharePoint Designer ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system sharing dialog box does not support customization.

So we couldn't add the prompt box when someone share files to Everyone.

Comment: Hi Julie, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you find any reply is helpful, please remember to mark it as answer.